# ASP.NET Core Restful Web API Https - Client Connection Certificate Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, ssl-certificate, asp.net-core-webapi

I built an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API that uses JWT for authentication; published the project and deployed to Windows 2019 server running IIS.

In IIS I created the site as follows:

1. created new Application Pool with 'No Managed Code' as the .NET CLR Version. Normally websites run inside an IIS worker process, but in .NET Core they run as a separate process, so there's no need for a .NET Runtime in the app pool.
2. created a new website for my ASP.NET Core application: selected the app pool previously created, set the Physical Path to the folder that contains the published app, selected HTTPS as the binding and also selected the certificate in the SSL certificate dropdown to the certificate I obtained from Comodo. I also set Hostname and checked 'Require server name indication' to true - because I have legacy WCF sites that have a different hostname but are on the same IP.

In Postman when I send a request with SSL Certificate Verification on, I get an **SSL Error: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames**. With SSL Verification off it works without error.

When creating a .NET desktop client using HttpClient and send a request to the site I get an error: **The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.**

When I Google this issue I find mostly articles related to people using self-signed certs on dev environments.

If I add the following code to my client it works without issue:

```
if (http_client == null)
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
         AllowAutoRedirect = false,
         ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => true,
         SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls
    };
    http_client = new HttpClient(handler);
}
```

**Why am I getting these SSL errors? Is my site not configured correctly?** I want to provide access to the site to developers soon, but I'm concerned they will have problems connecting. Some will be connecting from iOS environment, others from different website server platforms.

**Startup.cs** for the Web API

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();
    services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x => x.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true);

    // configure strongly typed settings objects
    var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

    // configure jwt authentication
    var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);
    services.AddAuthentication(x =>
    {
        x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(x =>
    {
        x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        x.SaveToken = true;
        x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            // set clockskew to zero so tokens expire exactly at token expiration time (instead of 5 minutes later)
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };
    });

    // configure DI for application services
    services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        gFunc.SetFolderPaths(true);
    }
    // global cors policy
    app.UseCors(x => x
       .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
       .AllowAnyMethod()
       .AllowAnyHeader()
       .AllowCredentials());
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(x => x.MapControllers());
}
```

Comment: There may be a problem with your certificate, but it is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my OP, I was previously running just one site on IIS that serves some legacy WCF services. I then added another site for a .NET Core Web API on the same IP address. To do this I had to enabled Server Name Indication (SNI) in IIS for the new site.

However, I discovered that when using SNI you have to turn it on for all sites not just one. I used ssllabs.com to run a test on the server and it was coming back with **Certificate Name Mismatch**, and returning a certificate for another domain/hostname.

Running "netsh http show sslcert" on the server showed both certificates, but the one for the WCF site was not linked to a hostname - just the IP address. So any request that came in to that IP address would always only get that certificate.

Enabling SNI for the other (WCF) site fixed the problem. Now each certificate is bound to IP/Hostname.